# Adding search filter for Issues board on YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

When you open Issues board it shows all the issues(Stories, Story Tasks, Bugs, Enhancements) but I want to show only Bugs and Enhancements.
Is there any way to show only these items?

I am not talking about Search criteria. You can search by Type and save your search but you have to click on your saved search every time you open the website. I tried to write code one `YouTrack Workflow Editor` but there is no way to show items by search criteria.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to change default context (which is 'Everything').
The best workarounds are:
-to use Saved Search (as you've already mentioned)
-to add this Saved Search as context.

Both variants require one extra click for showing sample you wish, but I beleive it's not so annoying.
Moreover, context allows you to execute other searches in respect of choosen context.

To add your saved search as context, navigate to Saved Searches section in side bar-> your saved search-> click Pin in a drop-down menu. Search will appear in Context Searches menu, top right corner of the page.